# How ev works and pass variable in function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, api, filereader

I am working on FileReader API with Javascript and got this code running to create thumbnails of Images I select. It works great. Here is my code

```
var fileHolder = new Array();
var addedImagesHolder = new Array();

$(document).on('change', '.uploadFiles', function()
{
     if(window.FormData)
     {
        fileHolder = this.files;
        CreateImageThumbnails();
     }
     else
     {
         alert('The File APIs are not supported.');
     }
});

function CreateImageThumbnails()
{
     for(var i=0; i<fileHolder.length; i++)
     {
         var uniqueID = Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);
         addedImagesHolder.push([fileHolder[i], uniqueID]);
         var fr = new FileReader();
         fr.onloadend = showFileInList;
         fr.readAsDataURL(fileHolder[i]);
     }
}

function showFileInList(ev)  //<--- How this ev works
{
     var img = new Image;
     img.onload = function() 
     {
         $('#thumbnails').append('<li>'+
                                    '<img src="'+ev.target.result+'"/>'+
                                    '<div class="ProgIndicBar"></div>'+
                                 '</li>');
     }   
     img.src = ev.target.result;
}
```

The above code works great but I got 2 problems.

1) How does the function **showFileInList** gets the **ev** as parameter? Where **ev** comes from?

2) How can I pass my uniqueID variable in **showFileInList** function as parameter along with **ev**? something like this

```
function showFileInList(ev, uid)
{
     //------
}
```

Comment: It comes from the code that calls the `onloadend` event, e.g., the `FileReader` event handler.

Comment: Use anonymous function `fr.onloadend = function(ev) {showFileInList(ev, uid);},`

Comment: @Tushar Thanks for such short answer of using anonymous function. I just missed this technique. Thanks it solved my problem no 2 but still cannot get the point of ev. As Dave said, it comes from onloadend event but how? because it's fr.onloadend = showFileInList; then how onloadevent sends event after the function showFileInList has been called off.

Comment: @Tushar that actually answers the question(s), not sure (beyond an explanation) anyone else could add to that.

Comment: I may be wrong but as I understood **fr.onloadend = showFileInList;** means the function showFileInList is called first and then the result is equal to fr.onloadend. Am I wrong? If wrong, please please teach me what  **fr.onloadend = showFileInList;** means

Comment: @AbdulJabbarWebBestow the javascript runtime passes an Event Object to event handlers when the event fires. Check MDN. As for the code in Tushar's comment, you are assigning the `showFileInList` function to the `onloadend` event of `fr`. When that event fires the function will be called with an Event Object with the details of the event (`ev`).

Comment: @AbdulJabbarWebBestow No, the function is not called, the function reference is assigned as callback function. And when some _asynchronous_ process is completed, the function is called with the parameters. This is called **event-driven** programming.